# wxpython:How can I get the size of a panel or let a image fit the size of panel

Tags: python, wxpython

I want to put an image into the center of a wxPanel, I am considering that I need to resize the image to fit the wxPanel. But I can't get the size of a wxPanel  dynamically. And here is a test code.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# wxboxsizer.py

import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, (-1, -1), wx.Size(500, 500))
        panel1 = wx.Panel(self, -1,style= wx.SIMPLE_BORDER)
        panel2 = wx.Panel(self, -1,style= wx.SIMPLE_BORDER)
        panel3 = wx.Panel(self, -1,style= wx.SIMPLE_BORDER)
        box = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        box.Add(panel1, 1,flag = wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL,border = 3 )
        box.Add(panel2, 1,flag = wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL,border = 3 )
        box.Add(panel3, 1,flag = wx.EXPAND |wx.ALL,border = 3)
        self.SetSizer(box)


class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        frame = MyFrame(None, -1, 'wxboxsizer.py')
        frame.Show(True)
        return True

app = MyApp(0)
app.MainLoop()
```

This code can let the 3 panels fit the frame perfectly, but how can I get the size of the panel dynamically.
Furthermore, how can I put an image into a panel, and let the image fit the panel dynamically?

**My solution:** I just got a method to get the size of panel when the frame is resized.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# wxboxsizer.py

import wx,os

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, (-1, -1), wx.Size(500, 500))
        self.panel1 = wx.Panel(self, -1,style= wx.SIMPLE_BORDER)
        panel2 = wx.Panel(self, -1,style= wx.SIMPLE_BORDER)
        panel3 = wx.Panel(self, -1,style= wx.SIMPLE_BORDER)
        box = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        box.Add(self.panel1, 1,flag = wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL,border = 3 )
        box.Add(panel2, 1,flag = wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL,border = 3 )
        box.Add(panel3, 1,flag = wx.EXPAND |wx.ALL,border = 3)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_SIZE, self.OnSize)
        self.SetSizer(box)

    def OnSize(self, event):
        size = self.GetSize()
        size2 = self.panel1.GetSize()
        print size,size2
        event.Skip()


class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        frame = MyFrame(None, -1, 'wxboxsizer.py')
        frame.Show(True)
        return True

app = MyApp(0)
app.MainLoop()
```

This code can show the size of panel when the frame is resized.

Comment: If panels are not resizing, you can call self.Layout() and/or self.Fit() in OnSize method. For image, you can use wx.Image to hold your image object and put that in wx.StaticBitmap and place this on the panel.

Answer (score 2):

The panel sizes are available after a `Show()`
Here is an example of both getting the panel sizes and fitting the same image into different size panels. 3 panels showing the same image. You would have to amend the `Aspect` calculation if you where showing the images in a vertical sizer.

```
import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, (-1, -1), wx.Size(500, 500))
        self.MaxImageSize = 500
        self.panel1 = wx.Panel(self)
        self.panel2 = wx.Panel(self)
        self.panel3 = wx.Panel(self)
        self.Image1 = wx.StaticBitmap(self.panel1, bitmap=wx.EmptyBitmap(self.MaxImageSize, self.MaxImageSize))
        self.Image2 = wx.StaticBitmap(self.panel2, bitmap=wx.EmptyBitmap(self.MaxImageSize, self.MaxImageSize))
        self.Image3 = wx.StaticBitmap(self.panel3, bitmap=wx.EmptyBitmap(self.MaxImageSize, self.MaxImageSize))

        box = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        box.Add(self.panel1, 1,flag = wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL,border = 3)
        box.Add(self.panel2, 2,flag = wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL,border = 3)
        box.Add(self.panel3, 3,flag = wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL,border = 3)
        self.SetSizer(box)
        Img1 = wx.Image('./image2.png', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG)
        Img2 = wx.Image('./image2.png', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG)
        Img3 = wx.Image('./image2.png', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG)
        self.Show()
        W,H = self.panel1.GetSize()
        IW = Img1.GetWidth()
        IH = Img1.GetHeight()
        NewW = W
        if IH>IW:
            Aspect = float(IW) /float(IH)
        else:
            Aspect = float(IH) / float(IW)
        NewH = W * Aspect

# scale the image, keeping ratio
        Img1 = Img1.Scale(NewW,NewH)
        self.Image1.SetBitmap(wx.BitmapFromImage(Img1))

        W,H = self.panel2.GetSize()
        NewW = W
        NewH = W * Aspect
# scale the image, keeping ratio
        Img2 = Img2.Scale(NewW,NewH)
        self.Image2.SetBitmap(wx.BitmapFromImage(Img2))

        W,H = self.panel3.GetSize()
        NewW = W
        NewH = W * Aspect
# scale the image, keeping ratio
        Img3 = Img3.Scale(NewW,NewH)
        self.Image3.SetBitmap(wx.BitmapFromImage(Img3))
        self.Fit()
        self.Layout()

class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        frame = MyFrame(None, -1, 'Fit images')
        frame.Show(True)
        return True

app = MyApp(0)
app.MainLoop()
```